# remove trailing spaces in a file only from non empty lines

Tags: sed, spaces, trailing

I know how to remove all trailing spaces from a file, e.g :

```
sed -i 's/  *$//' file
```

Is there a way to do it, but not in lines containing only spaces?

Something in the spirit of :

```
sed -i 's/[a-zA-Z0-9;}{]  *$/[a-zA-Z0-9;}{]/' file
                         ^ keep the original characters
```

Preferably, but not necessariliy, with sed.
Any linux supported solution will do.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure some other character appears before:

```
sed -r 's/([^\s])\s+$/\1/' file
```

This checks if a non-space character (`\s`) appears followed by any amount of spaces. If so, just print this non-space character back, so that the trailing spaces are removed.

#### Test

Using `cat -vet` to see the markers:

```
$ cat -vet a
hello    $
       $
bye   $
$ sed -r 's/([^\s])\s+$/\1/' a | cat -vet -
hello$
 $
bye$
```

Comment: If your sed supports `\s` for space then it probably also supports `\S` for non-space so you could use that instead of `[^\s]`.